# Symfony 2.X Services throwing exception

Tags: php, symfony, service

I am facing problem with services in Symfony 2.x version. When I try to use Services its giving me the following error

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function has() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\skerp8\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php line 202

in C:\wamp\www\skerp8\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php line 202
at ErrorHandler->handleFatalError() in C:\wamp\www\skerp8\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler.php line 219
at ErrorHandler->handleFatal() in C:\wamp\www\skerp8\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler.php line 0
at Controller->getDoctrine() in C:\wamp\www\skerp8\src\Skerp\ProductionBundle\Controller\RouteCardController.php line 3030
at RouteCardController->getRouteCardSummaryDetailsByRoutecardIdAction() in C:\wamp\www\skerp8\src\Skerp\InventoryBundle\Controller\BlockInventoryController.php line 467
at BlockInventoryController->updateAction() in C:\wamp\www\skerp8\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2951
at ??call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\skerp8\app\bootstrap.php.cache:2951}() in C:\wamp\www\skerp8\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2951
at HttpKernel->handleRaw() in C:\wamp\www\skerp8\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2923
at HttpKernel->handle() in C:\wamp\www\skerp8\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 3062
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle() in C:\wamp\www\skerp8\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2305
at Kernel->handle() in C:\wamp\www\skerp8\web\app_dev.php line 28
at ??{main}() in C:\wamp\www\skerp8\web\app_dev.php line 0
```

The following is my **config.yml** code

```
services:
    RouteCardControllerService:
        class: Skerp\ProductionBundle\Controller\RouteCardController
        arguments:
            container: "@service_container"
```

I am calling the above controller in BlockInventoryController.php with the following code.

```
$routecardControllerService = $this->get('RouteCardControllerService');
$routecardControllerService->updateRouteCardSummaryReportDetailsByRoutecardIdAction($routecardid)
```

In RouteCardController.php file

```
public function getRouteCardSummaryDetailsByRoutecardIdAction($routecardid){
    //Do something and return array of data
}

public function updateRouteCardSummaryReportDetailsByRoutecardIdAction($routecardid) {
    $routecardSummaryDetails = $this->getRouteCardSummaryDetailsByRoutecardIdAction($routecardid);
    //Do Something...
}
```

Why is it throwing an error. How should I implement a services so that I can access the methods of controller in other controller.

Comment: Could you please paste stack trace?

Comment: Okay I will add

Comment: What id the last record in symfony log? (dev.log or prod.log accordind to your environment)

Comment: @HonzaRydrych Can you please guide me where I can find that out.

Comment: projectdir/app/logs in Symfony2

Answer (score 0):

This is because of code:

```
if (!$this->container->has('doctrine')) {
```

in `Symfony` controller. You are not setting properly `container` service on your `RouteCardController` controller.

Please paste part of your controller where you are setting `container` service. Does you controller implement `ContainerAwareInterface`?

Note: this is really not recommended to inject `container` but services you really need.

Comment: His services.yml file is also messed up.

Comment: @Kamil Adryjanek Can you please redirect me which guides me how to create Services in symfony2, since I am new to it. I am not getting how to create one.

Comment: In your case this one will be useful: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html

Comment: @KamilAdryjanek Still facing the same problem if I follow the link  https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html please suggest some alternatives please

Comment: Please, paste your service class and service definition.